# R, How to convert data.frame (structured by dots) in list and xml

Tags: xml, r, list, dataframe

In R, how to convert a structure like that (separated by dots) in a R list (structured with "$"). The final aim is to convert it to xml after.
This structure is in two columns: with parameter in the first one and the value in second.

From :

```
Name                        | Project_name
Version                     | 1.0.3
GENERATION.Name             | Heater
GENERATION.Gestion_type     | 1
GENERATION.GENERATEUR.Pint  | 22
GENERATION.GENERATEUR.cce   | 3
GENERATION.ZONE.occupation  | 10
etc.
```

To :

```
<Name>Project_Name</Name>
<Version>1.0.3</Version>
<GENERATION>
   <Name>Heater</Name>
   <Gestion_type>1</Gestion_type>
   <GENERATEUR>
       <Pint>22</Pint>
       <cce>3</cce>
     </GENERATEUR>
   <ZONE>
       <occupation>10</occupation>
     </ZONE>
</GENERATION>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Here is some usefull solution (Jeff Allen) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256064/how-to-create-xml-from-r-objects-e-g-is-there-a-listtoxml-function

Comment: Yes, for the second step, from list to xml.

Comment: My main problem is to convert this dotted structure in R list