# Download mp3 file

Tags: r, xml, list, web, rvest

I would like to use a website from R. The website is http://soundoftext.com/ where I can download WAV. files with audios from a given text and a language (voice).

There are two steps to download the voice in WAV:
1) Insert text and Select language. And Submit
2) On the new window, click Save and select folder.

Until now, I could get the xml tree, convert it to list and modify the values of text and language. However, I don't know how to convert the list to XML (with the new values) and execute it. Then, I would need to do the second step too.

Here is my code so far:

```
require(RCurl)
require(XML)
webpage <- getURL("http://soundoftext.com/")
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
x<-xmlToList(pagetree)
# Inserting word
x$body$div$div$div$form$div$label$.attrs[[1]]<-"Raúl"
x$body$div$div$div$form$div$label$.attrs[[1]]

# Select language
x$body$div$div$div$form$div$select$option$.attrs<-"es"
x$body$div$div$div$form$div$select$option$.attrs
```

I have follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256064/how-to-create-xml-from-r-objects-e-g-is-there-a-listtoxml-function) approach but there is an error with "tag".

UPDATED: I just tried to use rvest to download the audio file, however, it does not respond or trigger anything. What am I doing wrong (missing)?

```
url <- "http://soundoftext.com/"
s <- html_session(url)
f0 <- html_form(s)
f1 <- set_values(f0[[1]], text="Raúl", lang="es")
attr(f1, "type") <- "Submit"
s[["fields"]][["submit"]] <- f1
attr(f1, "Class") <- "save"

test <- submit_form(s, f1)
```

Comment: You probably will have a better time with `rvest` package and its `html_form` function

Comment: Thank you @GGamba. I've modified the post with a code using your recommendation. However, it still does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your approach and it was worth a try.. that's what I'd write too.
The page is somewhat annoying in that uses jquery to append new divs at each request. I still think that should be possible to do with `rvest`, but I found a fun workaround using the `httr` package:

```
library(httr)    

url <- "http://soundoftext.com/sounds"

fd <- list(
  submit = "save",
  text = "Banana", 
  lang="es"
)

resp<-POST(url, body=fd, encode="form")
id <- content(resp)$id

download.file(URLencode(paste0("http://soundoftext.com/sounds/", id)), destfile = 'test.mp3')
```

Essentially when it send the `POST` request to the server, an `ID` come back, if we simply `GET` that `id` when can download the file.

Comment: Thank you again @GGamba. It can downloads the audio, however, the file has not length and it cannot be listen from any player. What is the problem?

Comment: Apologies, I haven't tested it. the Url the mp3 file resides is different, try this: `download.file(URLencode(paste0("http://soundoftext.com/static/sounds/", fd[['lang']], '/', fd[['text']], '.mp3')), 'test.txt')`

Comment: It works! Thank you. BTW, do you know how to solve the words with ` and ´ common in some languages?

Comment: pls consider upvoting

Comment: cannot open URL 'http://soundoftext.com/static/sounds/it/Ra%FAl.mp3': HTTP status was '404 NOT FOUND' This is trying "Raúl" as text

Comment: I got `trying URL 'http://soundoftext.com/static/sounds/it/Ra%C3%BAl.mp3'`. It's probably a `locale` problem. That's always a headache for me from a non-english country. Try `Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL', 'C')` but I can't help much more, may be worth a new question-

Comment: I'll check the configuration. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Creator of Sound of Text here. Sorry it took so long for me to find this post.

I just redesigned Sound of Text, so your html parsing probably won't work anymore.
*However,* there is now an API that you can use which should make things considerably easier for you.

You can find the documentation here: https://soundoftext.com/docs

I apologize if it's not very good. Please let me know if you have any questions.